# Most lightweight way to emulate a distributed system on linux

Tags: linux, docker, android-emulator, distributed-computing, distributed-system

So I am taking this distributed systems class in which projects are done by simulating a distributed system using android and multiple emulators. This approach is terrible for multiple reasons:

1. Android emulators are too effin resource consuming that my poor laptop crashes mostly.
2. Poor networking support between emulators. Need to do port forwarding on TCP and what not.

So what is the way to emulate a distributed system on my Linux machine that consumes minimal resources, mostly RAM and CPU time?

Is Docker the answer to all of this? Maybe create multiple containers with separate IP for each? Is that even possible?

Comment: Have you tried using Android-x86 on Virtualbox? Android-x86 runs quite a bit faster than the android emulator, and you can use bridged network connections on virtualbox to give each instance its own ip

Comment: Virtualbox will again use a lot of RAM for every virtual machine. Will have to allocate at least 1 GB of RAM to every instance. Not very resource optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run several docker containers on one Linux machine. Each container will get its own IP address and it will also be able to talk to other containers on the same host. How many systems do you want to simulate?

Comment: I want to simulate at least 5. How much resources would be required per system?

Comment: 5 should run easily on any Linux system unless you are doing some heavy computer within your docker containers. If you need to scale to 100s of containers you may need a heftier host.

Comment: I see. I should definitely explore this more. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

My team maintains several production distributed systems; and we have to unit test it in such a way that we can capture protocol bugs.

We have a stub implementation of clock and of the network that we inject into our classes. The network mimics the Message Passing model used in many distributed systems papers: pick a message at random and deliver it. This models network latencies and inconsistencies very well. We have other things built in: being able to block/release or drop messages to/from sets of hosts; and a simple tcp model.

With this simple addition our unit tests are now what we call *interaction tests*. We can very quickly add however many servers we want all running in single process on a laptop.

---

Oh, and after doing this, you'll know why global variables and singletons are a Bad Thing.